# How to add more than one container in body

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So, I'm really new to flutter or dart.
I looked at many tutorials, a bit hard to learn.

I need to know if I can, and how can I add more containers that contain Texts or Button in Flutter.

I already tried many things, but everything gives me an error.
I want to put some buttons in one container, and in another container I want to add some labels.
and I need to put these two containers at my Scaffold, how I do it?

or maybe how can I add two scaffolds on the same page, so I need labels at one and buttons in other.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp (MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Tittle',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar:AppBar(
          title: Text('My Title'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Text('Hello World),
        ), //Container
          # I WANT TO ADD ANOTHER CONTAINER HERE
      ), //Scaffold
    );  //MaterialApp
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different ways to achieve that. You can use the `Column` widget

```
Column(
   children: <Widget>[
      Container(),
      Container(),
   ],
)
```

and the result will be a set of child elements one under another. Another way of doing so is to use the `Row` widget

```
Row(
   children: <Widget>[
      Container(),
      Container(),
   ],
)
```

In this case, the result would be a set of elements displayed one next to another.

There are also a few more different ways that you can use to display a list of elements like `Stack` and `ListView`. Try them and choose the one that meets your requirements